# How can one change the Oxygen look away from Gtk aplications when having both Ubuntu and Kubuntu Desktop?

Tags: unity, kubuntu, 12.10, kde4

I have both Kubuntu and Ubuntu desktop installed on my laptop running 12.10. eventhough I enjoy the looks of KDE, when using Unity, aplications (firefox, thunderbird, filezilla, geany, amongst others ) and some dialogs from the system appear using the Oxigen look of KDE.

Is there a way to ensure the look of gtk when using Unity?

I have tried gnome-tweak-tool but all seems to point to using the Ambiance theme. nothing seems to fix this.

[image: desktop showing Geany on Ubuntu 12.10]

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to fix the issue by opening "kde system settings"  clicked on Application Apperance > GTK+ Apperance and switched all things from oxigengtk to Ambiance.

Problem Solved